# System of inequalities in multivariate polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Suppose there are $k$ non-zero homogeneous polynomials $P^1(.),\cdots, P^k(.)$, each of degree $r$ in $n$ variables, such that $P^j(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \geq 0$ for all $(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \geq 0$, for all $j \in [k]$. Under what conditions (on the $P^j(.)$'s) would there exist an $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n_{+}$ such that $P^j(\alpha) > 0$ for all $j \in [k]$?

I can see that for each $j$ there exists an $\alpha^j  \in \mathbb{R}^n_{+}$ such that $P^j(\alpha^j) > 0$ (otherwise $P^j(.)$ would become the zero polynomial). But not sure whether and how we can construct an $\alpha$ that will work for all $P^j(.)$'s.

EDIT: I tried to solve the above question as follows.

Fix $j$. Suppose there exists an open ball $B_{\epsilon}(\overline{x}) \subset \mathbb{R}^n_{+}$ such that $P^j(x) = 0$ for all $x \in B_{\epsilon}(\overline{x})$. But this means $P^j(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n_{+}$. (Is this true? I'm not able to prove this as of now but it seems true) Hence $P^j(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n_{+}$. Hence $P^j(.)$ is the zero polynomial. Contradiction. Therefore for each $j$, the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n_{+}: P^j(x)=0\}$ is a measure zero set in $\mathbb{R}^n_{+}$. Hence the union of such sets for all $j$ is also measure zero. Hence for almost all $x 
\in \mathbb{R}^n_{+}$ $P^j(x) > 0$ for all $j$.

But I'm not able to prove exactly how being equal to zero for an open ball of points implies being the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

A nonzero polynomial of degree $r$ has some $r$th partial derivative which is a nonzero constant. That's impossible for a function which is zero on an open set.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be an open ball with center $x_0$. Then $B$ contains $x_0+\sum_{i=1}^n t_i e_i$, $\vert t_i\vert<\varepsilon$ for all $i$, where $e_i$ is the $i$-th unit vector and $\varepsilon$ is a suitable positive number. Thus, if the polynomial $P$ vanish on $B$, es geht that $P(u)=0$ for all $u\in B_1\times B_2\times\ldots\times B_n$ with all $B_i$ infinite.
This implies that $P=0$ as discussed here: [Zeros of polynomial over an infinite field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2789699/zeros-of-polynomial-over-an-infinite-field/2789760#2789760)