# Can a non-zero homogeneous multivariate polynomial have an infinite number of zeros?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I know similar questions have been asked many times but somehow I'm still confused.

Please refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808331/prove-that-homogeneous-multivariate-polynomial-reduces-to-the-zero-polynomial-gi/2808598?noredirect=1#comment5798106_2808598) question and the comments discussion on the first answer for context.

> Let $P(x_1,\cdots,x_r)$ be a homogeneous polynomial such that
>   $P(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_r) = 0$ for an uncountably infinite number of $(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_r)
>  \in \mathbb{R}^r_{+}$ (We can also assume there exists an open ball such that $P(.)$ is zero for all $\alpha$ in that ball). Does that mean $P(.)$ is the zero polynomial?

In my understanding a non-zero homogeneous polynomial in finite number of variables will have a finite number of zeros, hence the result follows. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The parenthetical comment is crucial.  Otherwise consider $P(x,y)=x-y$.  This is homogeneous and vanishes on the uncountable set $\{(a,a)|a\in\mathbb R \}$, but there is no open ball in $\mathbb R^2$ on which $P$ vanishes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried to use this reasoning (though there are some mistakes) in my attempt at this question. I would request you to consider having a look, in case you are interested. Thanks again. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2811434/system-of-inequalities-in-multivariate-polynomials

Comment: How does the three-variable polynomial $X^2+Y^2-Z^2$ fit in with your understanding? It has infinitely many zeros, doesn’t it?