# Series that vanish for infintely many values

Tags: power-series

How to prove that if i got a series $f \in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ that vanishes for all $X,Y \in [-1,1]$ then all his coefficients must be $0$ ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: $X\in\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ vanishes at all the points $(X,Y)=(0,y)$, for $y\in\mathbb{R}$, but it is not zero.

Comment: Not sure if this helps or not but I think you should only consider the case for uncountable zeros since if it is countable, we can construct the sequence $a_{n}=(-1)^{n}$ to obtain the divergence series $S_{n}$ with countably many zeros.

Comment: Yes of course you're both right, I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Zeros of polynomial over an infinite field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2789699/zeros-of-polynomial-over-an-infinite-field/2789760#2789760). This answers the question for polynomials. If you speak about power series, converging for all $(x,y)\in [-1,1] \times [-1,1]$, the same holds true by the identity theorem for analytic functions   in several variables.

Answer (score 0):

If $f=0$ in $(0,1)^2,$ then all partial derivatives of $f$ at $(0,0)$ are $0.$ Couple that with the following: If $f(x,y) = \sum_{m=0}^{M}\sum_{n=0}^{N} a_{mn}x^my^n,$ then $D_x^mD_y^n f(0,0) = m!n!a_{mn}.$